# Tesla K80, nvidia-smi cannot communicate with driver issue

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I tried to install CUDA driver with Tesla K80 in Ubuntu 18.04.
After all the successful steps, I can't connect to my GPU.

I have checked and `lspci` recognized my card. My PC is using an Intel i5 CPU and a Gigabyte Mainboard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `lshw -C display`, is the K80 unclaimed?